# simpledateformat for month and day in month only

Tags: java, android, date, simpledateformat

I require this format MonthDay, example `0422`

I'm creating

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMdd");
```

and giving it the current month and current day

```
curDate = sdf.parse(curMon+""+curDay);
```

but I'm getting this format:

```
Thu Jun 07 00:00:00 CEST 1973
```

What do I need to do?

Comment: A standard `Date` has no format. If you use `System.out.println(someDate)`, it just prints the date object with the default formatting (as in your example), irrespective of how you created that object.

Comment: if you already have curMon and curDay, why do you need a SimpleDateFormat ?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `parse`, use `format` as follows:

```
SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("MMdd");
String d = s.format(new Date());
System.out.println(d);
```

This will generate, since today is 27th May:

```
0527
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope  below code will help you...

```
    strDate="2014-08-19 15:49:43";

    public String getMonth(String strMonth) {

    int month = Integer.parseInt(strMonth.substring(0, 2));
    int day = Integer.parseInt(strMonth.substring(strMonth.length() - 2,
            strMonth.length()));

    String d = (new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths()[month - 1]).substring(
            0, 3) + " " + day;
    return d;
}


 public static String smallDate(String strDate) {

    String str = "";
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat fmInput = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date date = fmInput.parse(strDate);

        SimpleDateFormat fmtOutput = new SimpleDateFormat("MMdd");
        str = fmtOutput.format(date);

        str = getMonth(str);
         Log.d("Output date: "+str);
        return str;


    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use like that

```
Date date; // your date
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);

        String month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH).toString();
        String day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH).toString();
        String mmdd=month+""+day;
```